# Facebook Client OAuth settings domain not working with query strings

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the Auth working with Facebook but it keeps on telling me that my redirect URL is not working.

In the **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** I have the following

```
 https://localhost
```

The issue is that, I'm passing some additional query string to my callback, like

```
 https://localhost?uuid=something&service=my_service
```

When attempting to Auth, I do get the request popup and then I get a redirect URL but then Facebook is telling me that the URL is not allowed.

[image: facebook error]

If I test `https://localhost?uuid=something&service=my_service` in Facebook's **Redirect URI Validator** it's telling me it's not valid

How can I add a a URL including a dynamic query string ? I've tried

```
 https://localhost*
```

But Facebook is telling me this is not a valid URL and won't let me save/add this URL.

Comment: You can't. Set a session variable before redirecting, and it'll be there when they come back.

Comment: Long story short, we can't because the URL is returning to our API which is not hosted on the same domain as our front-end...

Comment: Consider abusing the `state` parameter, then. Put your data in it as JSON.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz I have answered my own question with your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ceejayoz put me on the right track, I will answer my own question, that might help someone else.

Additional data must be passed in a `state` parameter such as

```
 $data = json_encode($some_std_class);
 $pdata = $fb_helper->getPersistentDataHandler();
 $pdata->set('state', $data);
 $login_url = $fb_helper->getLoginUrl($my_url, $my_permissions);
```